# Application class not found Exception when download from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I updated an app in goolge play store with a new version.Now if app open then Application class not found exception occurs.

App works fine if the apk install directly .But not from play store.

Crash analytics report says

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.xxx.xx.GetJsonArrayFromChannelUrl: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xxx.xxx.GetJsonArrayFromChannelUrl" on path: /data/app/com.xx.xx-2.apk
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4584)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xxxx.fetchdata.GetJsonArrayFromChannelUrl" on path: /data/app/com.xx.xx-2.apk
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:985)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:499)
```

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: it happens sometimes.. check your libraries and clean your project than make signed apk again.

Comment: Have you added application class to manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps.

- Clean your libraries
- Right click on project > Android Tools > Fix Project properties
- Project > Clean